# Terminal stuck at white starting nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup a nodejs based server, but unfortunately, when ever I run it via terminal, `node app.js` it returns console log thing what ever I declare in `app.js` file, and after that, it stuck, I can't not use it to process more tasks.

```
var http = require('http');
var express    = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get('/files/:hash/:title', function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.params));
  console.log('Done');
});
app.listen(8080);
console.log('Server running');
```

and terminal's response

```
root@mrboota13:/var/Node# node app.js
Server running
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
```

Comment: What did you expect it to do? I don't see where the error is here.

Comment: open another terminal window and do everything!

Comment: I want that server work perfectly, and I can start another process, like php server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the Node process is still running, waiting for new HTTP requests to arrive.

To stop the process, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+C

Comment: How can I force to run in background

Comment: You can use something like this: `nohup node app.js &`